# How much basic reputation needed to become a moderator on any network site?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators

I think the answer of my question is 10k then, how come [this user](https://stackexchange.com/users/237028/arie-litovsky?tab=accounts) become moderator of different network sites, including StackOverflow.com?

P.S. I read his profile, he's working at StackExchange Inc. Only that reason made him a moderator?

Comment: I think it's 3k to run/get nominated.

Comment: look up [Moderator Elections](http://stackoverflow.com/election)

Comment: "members of the Stack Exchange, Inc. Team have the option to carry diamonds on any site..." ([Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192/165773))

Comment: @gunr2171 SO is a special case, most other sites set it at 300. Also, the [most recent election page](http://stackoverflow.com/election/5) lists the limit as 4239... (?)

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii after the nomination phase is finished, the limit is set to the lowest reputation of all candidates. In this case, [Wobbuffet](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5#post-21820676) had the lowest rep with 4239.

Comment: @l4mpi actually that (also?) happens when all slots are filled. A new candidate then needs more reputation than the candidate with the lowest amount of rep to still be able to nominate themselves.

Comment: Bart"s explanation makes sense; changing the criteria after nominations are over would be an odd thing to do..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Community moderation is indeed tied to reputation - you can go to the privileges page (linked from the help center) to find out what each reputation bracket gives you.

Things like voting to close/reopen, voting to delete/undelete and so on.

---

Other than that, sites have diamond moderators (with a diamond next to their name) - these are either appointed by Stack Exchange staff (during public beta) and later on are elected by the community. Either way, these are community members. They get more moderation powers than high reputation community members.

---

Stack Exchange employees that need it, get a moderator status (so they can use mod only tags, for example).

Arie is one of our iOS developers - as such he responds to bug reports and feature requests for the iOS app, and as such needs moderator access.

Comment: How come Jon Skeet is not a moderator? Did he decline to do it? he has more than enough rep, and active enough...

Comment: @Stacker-flow - community moderation means access to things like close and delete votes. He certainly does vote to close/delete posts (and whatever other moderation related privileges that he has via reputation). As for becoming a diamond moderator - people nominate themselves and the people who get voted are elected. Jon never nominated himself. I can only assume he has no interest in becoming a diamond moderator.